# How to compare two arrays to find common elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find a number x for which x = y^4 = z^6 = 5k = 2l. Is there a way of comparing the arrays of fourth and sixth power numbers to find the smallest common element?

```
    int[] fourth = new int[1000];
    int[] sixth = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i*i*i*i % 10 == 0) {
            int count = 0;
            fourth[count] = (i*i*i*i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i*i*i*i*i*i % 10 == 0) {
            int count = 0;
            sixth[count] = (i*i*i*i*i*i);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `1000^6` is quite a bit larger than can fit in an `int`.  The top ends of your arrays are going to be full of gargage.  You might want to change those to `long[]`.

Comment: @azurefrog Sorry it was a joke because of the visually ambiguous choice of variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: `i^4 % 10 == 0` means `i % 10 == 0`, so you have `10, 20, 30, ..., 990`.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i+=10){
    int count = 0;
    fourth[count] = (i^4);
    count++;
}
```

To further improve, you can simply do a math trick.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i+=10){
    double val = i^(4/6);
    if (val % 10 == 0 and 0<val<1000)
       system.out.println((val^(6/4)) + " is a number you are looking for!!!.");
}
```

You don't need to iterate 1 to 10 and you don't need to calculate all values.

**EDIT:**

It seems you want to calculate the `x = y^4 = z^6 = 5k = 2l`, assuming `x,y,z,k,l` are integers, x should be divisible by 10 and it should be the 4th and 6th power of some integers which means that 12th power of some integers.

Here is the list of numbers that you are looking for:

```
for (i = 10; i < 1000; i+=10){
    long long a = i ^ 12;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```